# Changing a part or portion of console output

Tags: d

Is there a way to change something that has already been written to the console?

For example, I'd like to change a line already written from this:

```
_ Foo
```

... to this:

```
+ Foo
```

Although ideally this would work on both Windows (powershell or command line) and Linux (shell), a Linux-only solution would be acceptable.

I'm unfamiliar with standard input and output, so forgive me if this is a basic question.

Comment: Is the cursor still on that line? You might be able to output "\r+ Foo" followed by  a stdout.flush to overwrite the current line.

Comment: Many console windows can behave like a classical terminal in so far as appropriate control sequences of characters (often involving the Esc character) can move the cursor to any point in the window. VT100 is a very common choice. If this is the case with command windows on Windows, I don't know.

Comment: On Windows, it is quite simple, the windows console api will even let you overwrite the buffer without moving the cursor. But that is all more complex than just using the single line carriage return...

Answer (score 1):

If your cursor is still on the same line you can do this:

```
write("_ Foo");
stdout.fllush;//To force the displaying of the text now.
writeln("\r+ Foo"); //Output will be replaced
```

But this will not work:

```
writeln("_ Foo"); //Equivalent to as `write("_ Foo\n");`
stdout.fllush;//To force the displaying of the text now
writeln("\r+ Foo"); //Output will not be replaced (it will be on new line).
```

You can also do this to erase characters individually:

```
write("_ Foo");
stdout.fllush;//To force the displaying of the text now
writeln("\b+ Foo"); //Output will be "_ Fo+ Foo"
```

I have not found a way to erase previous lines (and I think this is intentional).

Comment: Don't forget you can `stdout.flush();` instead of writing a line if you want to overwrite without advancing. Some programs do this to show like a spinning thingy. Awkward to do code in comments, but check this out: `import std.stdio;
import core.thread;
void main(){
 foreach(i; 1..10) {
  write("\r-"); stdout.flush();
  Thread.sleep(40.msecs);
  write("\r\\"); stdout.flush();
  Thread.sleep(40.msecs);
  write("\r/"); stdout.flush();
  Thread.sleep(40.msecs);
 }
 writeln();
}`

Comment: How do uou mean intentional?

Comment: @ArndtJonasson The console is designed to have a log of past messages.  If you could erase previous lines it could mess up past logs.  I think whoever chose the available commands, intentionally did not include commands to erase previous lines.

Comment: Are you talking about the Windows command window specifically?

Comment: @ArndtJonasson No, any (I think).

Comment: You can learn about terminals here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal

Comment: @ArndtJonasson What in there do you want me to learn?  Am I wrong, or do you just think I will find it interesting?